# Autofac with string configuration but without Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration

Tags: autofac

The documentation for Autofac has a section for registering components with XML or JSON but it relies on Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration. Is there a way to do without without loading the string into that extension first?

My environment is based on the latest Xamarin.Forms and Autofac.

Cheers,
Luiz

Answer (score 0):

The config mechanism provided uses that extension. If you don't want Microsoft. Extensions.Configuration then you'll need to roll your own configuration mechanism.